# intesection of a closed set with an open set

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R^d$, $A$ closed and $B$ open. If $x\in A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ does there exist $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(x)\subseteq A\cap B$?

Comment: If $d=1$, $A=\{0\}\subset (-1,1)=:B$, there isn't any open ball centered at $0$ and contained in $A$.

Comment: ah yes. good example

Answer (score 2):

as $x\in B$, and $B$ is open so there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subseteq B$, but our $B_{\epsilon}$ may not be in the intersection. So it is ingeneral not true, for example in Real line, $A=\{0\}$, $B=(-1,1)$